# How to check if array1 has all the values of array2?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays.

```
array1 = [13, 15,18,19, 25]
array2 = [{id:13, label: 'value1'},{id:15,label:'value2'},{id:25, label:'value3'}]
```

How to check if all the values of array2.id is present in array1?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+check+values+array+another+array+site:stackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: There is nothing reactjs related in this question

Comment: `const checker = (arr, target) => target.every(({id}) => arr.includes(id)); console.log(checker(array1,array2))`

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan. You are life saver!!

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over array 2 and check that the `id` from every element is included in array 1.

```
array2.every(({ id }) => array1.includes(id));
```

```js
const array1 = [13, 15, 18, 19, 25];
const array2 = [{
  id: 13,
  label: 'value1'
}, {
  id: 15,
  label: 'value2'
}, {
  id: 25,
  label: 'value3'
}];

const res = array2.every(({ id }) => array1.includes(id));

console.log(res);
```